# Error while using INNER JOIN in C# Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

Why am I getting an error when I use Inner join in C#? The query is working when I try it in Access.

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    command.Connection = connection;
    string query = "SELECT BookID, BookName, CategoryDescription, Language, AuthorName, YearPublished FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN (tblAuthor INNER JOIN tblBook ON tblAuthor.AuthorID = tblBook.AuthorID) ON tblCategory.CategoryID = tblBook.CategoryID";
    command.CommandText = query;

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not into Access, but is that `INNER JOIN` between brackets ok? It's not valid T-SQL at least. Have you tried if a very simple select, and then start adding stuff back to see where it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's because you're using the keyword `language` in your query. you can get around this by changing it to `[Language]`

Change your query from

```
string query = "SELECT BookID, BookName, CategoryDescription, Language, AuthorName, YearPublished FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN (tblAuthor INNER JOIN tblBook ON tblAuthor.AuthorID = tblBook.AuthorID) ON tblCategory.CategoryID = tblBook.CategoryID";
```

to

```
string query = "SELECT BookID, BookName, CategoryDescription, [Language], AuthorName, YearPublished FROM tblCategory INNER JOIN (tblAuthor INNER JOIN tblBook ON tblAuthor.AuthorID = tblBook.AuthorID) ON tblCategory.CategoryID = tblBook.CategoryID";
```

Just to be safe, always use square brackets([]) around all column names and table names.

For future reference, here's a list of keywords for Access 2007. It might have grown since:

[Access Reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?CorrelationId=0114329f-35f7-4be7-b405-124d0b5fec9a&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010030643)